# RedisSessionStateProvider ERR unknown command 'EVAL'

Tags: stackexchange.redis

When I run Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider locally, I get the following error:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException: ERR unknown command 'EVAL'
```

I have installed the latest RedisSessionStateProvider from nuget.

Web config:

```
 <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
  <providers>

    <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="" accessKey="" ssl="false" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Comment: `EVAL` is introduced in redis 2.6; what version of redis are you running locally? and have you changed the configuration (in particular the command map)?

Comment: Thanks - that was it. Am running it on windows so not easy to get redis server.

Comment: just `cinst redis-64` or `install-package redis-64`; pretty eary to get ;p

Comment: ha, yes just found that out (see below). thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was running a version of redis server pre 2.6.

Quick easy way to get redis server for windows is via chocolatey.

Install from here: https://chocolatey.org/

Then get redis using command from here:
https://chocolatey.org/packages/redis-64/3.0.501

Then go to C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\redis-64 and run redis-server.exe

You'd then need to install as a service (see notes in C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\redis-64)

OR just get a windows installer msi from here (even easier if you don't mind the version too much i.e. just for development) https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases

Comment: I would put the GitHub link first. I would say that's easier

Answer (score 3):

You should upgrade your Redis as @SSED said. You can download 32 bit version of redis here: 
https://github.com/cuiwenyuan/Redis-Windows-32bit

Also if there is another error "Active machine refused It" you should run `redis-server.exe` file after downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if your server instance is greater than or equal to 2.6, but the `EVAL` command has been renamed explicitly. The latter is something that is sometimes done for security reasons on `redis` servers that are offered as a service (e.g. CloudFoundry)