# Trying to resolve dependencies: Changing .NET Standard Library to NET Core - Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives

Tags: redis, .net-core, nuget-package, .net-standard

I am running Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. I am trying to use Redis Cache for .Net core applications. Since, the developed package is targeting .Net Standard Library. I downloaded the code from github and trying to change the dependecies my self.

Here are the projects:

[image]

First, I am trying to chage the Abstractions Class Library to target .*Net Core*, then i tried to add the *Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives*, Since the version 1 does not support .NET Core. I added the final pre package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives -Version 1.0.0-rc1-final -Pre
```

It cannot resolve, saying that

> The dependency  Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives >= 1.0.0-rc1-final could not be resolved.

How Can I fix that to make it work for .NET Core? How is .NET Core 1 different from .NET Core 5, since these are dependencies of the package I installed?

[image]

Why all the packages support .NET Standard Libary and not .NET Core?

Comment: Seems you are using outdated tag. With tag 1.0.0 it works flawlessly. Only changes to project.json required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno what exactly you're doing, but rc1 references seem wrong, now that ASP.NET Core RTM is out for several months.

I grabbed the 1.0.0 sourced (you have to specifically choose the 1.0.0 tag. Master branch is based on ASP.NET Core 1.1).

Only thing I changed is `project.json` (I unloaded the other unloaded unrelated projects and test projects except `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.Test`.

This is my `project.json` (of `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis`):

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Distributed cache implementation of Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.IDistributedCache using Redis.",
  "packOptions": {
    "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/aspnet/caching"
    },
    "tags": [
      "cache",
      "distributedcache",
      "redis"
    ]
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "warningsAsErrors": true,
    "keyFile": "../../tools/Key.snk",
    "nowarn": [
      "CS1591"
    ],
    "xmlDoc": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "1.0.0",
    "StackExchange.Redis.StrongName": "1.1.608"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": { },
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": { },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime": {
          "type": "build"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

No changes required in `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions`.

Alternatively you can use `StackExchange.Redis` instead of `StackExchange.Redis.StrongName` which isn't strong named (signed). Not sure if the so created/compiled package will be signed with the same key as the other packages, which may create issues later. If you use unsigned one then it also may create issues, if your application is strong named itself (or you have business requirement that all assemblies are strong signed).

This compiles and the unit tests pass, didn't test further.

As for the rest of your question:

".NET Core 5" nuget target is `dnx50` which was used up until ASP.NET Core rc1. With rc2 ASP.NET Core switched to the dotnet-cli and DNX is unsupported now and won't receive any further updates. With rc2 the `netstandard` was introduced to simplify creation of class libraries which can target most of the platforms available (full .NET Framework, .NET Core, WinRT/WindowsPhone/Windows8/Windows10, mono, Xamarin, etc). You can learn more about the [.NET Standard Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library).

Comment: I need to get rid of `netstandard1.5` since I am using `netcoreapp1.0`, isn't that what should i be doing to reference `Redis.Cache` since my ASP.NET Core App also references `netcoreapp1.0` and cannot resolve the redis cache dependecy.

Comment: `netcoreapp1.0` should be able to handle `netstandard1.5`. `netstandard` is for class libraries, `netcoreapp1.0` is for executables http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library. The dependencies linked in your question are ancient relicts of pre-rc2 times, before there was netstandard

Comment: The issue you were facing in your previous question is that the M.E:Caching.Redis package only targeted `net451` but not `netstandard1.x`. The above change adds the `netstandard1.5` target and uses an updated verison of StackExchange.Redis client

Comment: In .NET Framework we were used to reference the dlls of the class library, now how to reference the new `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis` project without adding the class libraries to my solution. Thanks

Comment: create a nuget package, place it in a private nuget repository (self hosted, cloud hosted, VSTS) or in a folder on the filesystem and add an entry to the nuget feed list http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/hosting-packages/local-feeds